# Define a class student with the following specification (remaining que below)

Tags: c++

I dont understand why i am not getting total.

The question is

> Define a class student with the following specification:Private
>   members of class student admno integer sname 20 character eng.
>   math, science float total float ctotal() a function to calculate eng +
>   math +     science with float return type. Public member function of
>   class student     Takedata() Function Public member function of class
>   student Takedata() Function     float ctotal() a function to calculate
>   eng + math + science with floa return     type. Public member function
>   of class student Takedata() Function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
    private:
    int admno;
    char sname[20];
    float english,maths,science;
    float total;
    float ctotal()
    {
        total=(english+maths+science);
        return(total);
    }
    public:
        void Takedata()
        {
            cout<<"Enter the value of admno:";
            cout<<" sname :";
            cout<<"eng :";
            cout<<"science:";
            cout<<"maths:";
            cin>>admno;

            cin>>sname;

            cin>>english;

            cin>>science;

            cin>>maths;

        }
        Student(): total(0.0)  //constructor
        {
        }
        friend float func(Student);
        void Showdata()
        {
            cout<<"adm no:"<<admno;
            cout<<"sname:"<<sname;
            cout<<"eng"<<english;
            cout<<"science"<<science;
            cout<<"maths"<<maths;
        }
};
   float func(Student t)
   {
    t.total;
    return t.total;
   }
   int main()
   {
    Student s1;
    s1.Takedata();
    s1.Showdata();
    cout<"total is:";
    cout<<func(s1);

   }
```

Comment: You should use reference in "func" function :)

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting total"? For some specified input, what output do you expect and what output do you actually get? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Replace `t.total;` with `t.ctotal();`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `t.total` with `t.ctotal()` in

```
float func(Student t)
{
    t.total;
    return t.total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

func should be defind like this

```
   float func(Student t)
   {
    return t.ctotal();
   }
```

also edit

```
   cout<"total is:";
```

to

```
   cout<<"total is:";
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to make either total or method ctotal() public. 
Then call either one of them from

```
public:
    float total;
float func(Student t)
{
    t.total;
    return t.total;
}
```

OR
    public:
        float ctotal() { 
            total=(english+maths+science); 
            return(total); 
        }

```
float func(Student t)
{
    return t.ctotal();
}
```